# What is DigestUtils sha256 encoding equivalent from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, apache-commons, sha, sha256

I call following and create the password hash.

```
ByteString password = ByteString.copyFrom(DigestUtils.sha256("mypassword"));
```

But now I need to send the sha256 converted password message from client (JavaScript). I tired to use CryptoJS as following

```
 var pass = CryptoJS.SHA256(document.getElementById('password').value);
    var passhash = pass.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)
    login(passhash);
```

I tried all Base64, Latin1, and Hex types to get the string. But it will not produce the same password as the one in Java

Comment: Use [`bcrypt`](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

Comment: But sha is fixed. Its used in server side authentication. May be next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with character encoding. Following fixed the problem.

in JS:

```
var password = pass.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf16);
```

In Java:

```
byte[] passhash = jsCryptoString.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```